# Angular2: Load templateUrl only on demand

Tags: angular

Is it possible in Angular2 to load the template only when the component should be displayed?

In the moment when I declare a components with templateUrl, all the templates loaded on the start of the application.

Comment: You are probably looking for lazy loading.

Comment: You can do lazy loading on the route , but not the tempate.

Comment: Generally , if the component is not loaded , template won't be loaded , and it makes sense

Comment: You can't load the component , but not the view , doesn't make sense